# Google API's client library does not execute callback

Tags: javascript, html, google-api, google-api-client

All the Google API descriptions mentionds that after Javascript client library has loaded, this should fire the function it's give to `?onload`

Here is a test code I wrote, but myFunc doesn't get activated. Anyone can help?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Test </title>
<meta charset='utf-8' />


<script>
 function myFunc(){
 
 document.write( "Hi" );
 }  
</script>
 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=myFunc"></script>
 
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: need to improve heading! refer : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=myFunc
this passes a parameter "onload=myFunc"  to "https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"

change this to its attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox says in the console:

> A call to document.write() from an asynchronously-loaded external script was ignored.

Chrome says something similar:

> Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.

Try to use something other than `document.write`.

```html
<script>
 function myFunc(){
 
 document.body.innerHTML='oh yeah';
 }  
</script>
 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=myFunc"></script>
```

---

- Use of [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) is discouraged because it replaces the whole document if it is executed after the document was loaded.
- [Learn how to debug JavaScript](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging).

Answer (score 0):

the function is executed
the problem seem in the document.write();
it's generate the following error on chrome console

Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.

Comment: How is this different from  my answer?

Comment: Refresh more often ;)

Answer (score -1):

You've just got some quotation mark messiness. Try putting quotes at end of script location, removing the `onload` from the `src` property. Then set the `onload` property to `myFunc()` with the parentheses.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Test </title>
<meta charset='utf-8' />


<script>
 function myFunc(){
 
 document.write( "Hi" );
 }  
</script>
 
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="//apis.google.com/js/client.js" 
        onload="myFunc()"></script>
 
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Amazing!. Thank you. That was the missing piece of the puzzle.

Comment: I actually clicked the up-arrow. I am abit confused too. It says "vote up requires 15 reputations" and gives the -1 ?!? I have a new account but I would love to endorse you. Any ideas?

Comment: I downvoted you because you didn't provide any explanation for your changes. See how nice it is to get explanations for certain actions? You are also  potentially changing the behavior of the code: The function will now be executed by the browser when the script was loaded, it's not passed to and executed by `client.js` anymore.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the intention of the code. The function name is supposed to be passed to `client.js`. See https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js

Comment: Thanks, @FelixKling. I commented on my post. Now, on you're 'potentially-changing-the-code-behavior bit', I'd say it's a reasonable assumption to make that `myFunc` will not be defined in "cllient.js" -- since defined in preceding code, especially.

Comment: I'm confused by the last statement. Functions defined in earlier scripts are always accessible by code loaded in later scripts.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is a reason that `client.js` expects the function name passed as argument to itself and not a callback set on the `script` element. For example, `client.js` may loads other scripts asynchronously, and the callback should be called after *those* scripts have been loaded. However, I don't know for sure, and while your solution may still work, the explanation of why the code doesn't work is incorrect.

Comment: Actually, it looks like I'm right: `client.js?onload=myFunc` makes this call: `gapi.load("client", {callback: window["myFunc"], ..})`. `gapi.load` is an asynchronous call and `window["myFunc"]` seems to be called after that call was made. You are changing the code so that `myFunc` is called after `client.js` was loaded, which is a big difference.

Comment: @FelixKling, That's actually the same example I am following to make and API call to Google analytic. I have `<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>`
and my handleClientLoad contains : `function handleClientLoad() {
 
/**/ docuemnt.write("loading");
 
        gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
        window.setTimeout(checkAuth,1);
      }`   The least I should see it "loading" on screen, right?

Comment: @Ojen: As I tried to show in my answer, browsers don't seem to allow to call `document.write` from callbacks that are invoked by asynchronously loaded scripts. What about that is not clear?

Comment: @FelixKling, It's crystal clear now. Thanks for the explanation. I didn't have your code snippet expanded.

Comment: Looks like you win, my friend. Great answer. I'm still a bit irritated of the DV as my answer helped the OP, but I'll live. :) I like your answer better anyway, @FelixKling. Cheers